# Make Camera and Environment follow player smoothly and also zoomable

Tags: unity-game-engine, parallax, smooth-scrolling

I am making a 2d side scroller car racing game. The Player is a car that moves on a 2d terrain already created. The Camera follows the Player.

I also wanted to created more dept by making the background follow y-axis of player so that the background doesn't look like a plain picture.

The effect I am wanting to replicate is that when the player jumps the camera just zoom's out. I am using a perspective camera so it zooms out by moving it slightly away (more) from the Player. The effect isn't smooth.

The platform is using 2d edge collider. The movement gave me motion sickness and I just don't know what I should be doing to make this follow nicely.

I have tried using smooth damp that gave me spring effect which isn't needed here. I used Lerp which just doesn't work at all, It's dang slow and when I make it fast it just the same undesirable behaviour. The `MoveTowards` works a bit but not quite really. The smoothness is just not what I want.

```c#
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (CarController.Instance != null)
    {
        newPos = TargetPos + camOffSet;
        if (!CarController.Instance.IsGrounded && CarController.Instance.CanZoomOut)
        {
            float zz = Mathf.Clamp(-10 - newPos.y, -20, -10);
            newPos.z = Mathf.Clamp(-10 - newPos.y, -20, -10);
            newPos.x += (zz * -0.4f);
        }
        else
        {
            newPos.z = -10;
        }
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, newPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

For reference, my game is pretty much similar to the *I Hate Zombies* shown in [this](https://youtu.be/YQZoBC1hVyk?t=31s) video.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please send a code example how do you move the camera, because it's difficult to understand what happens without samples?

Usually it's enough to use combination of [Vector3.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) and [Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

Comment: Hello, I have added the code. Actually I wanted to make my camera ignore the turbulence. My Camera is focusing
check video https://youtu.be/xO_mEXo6mNA